# Rotate model in x axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rotating my model using mouse drag in y axis only. That is, direction of mouse towards Left/Right. With `eventData.delta.x`, the mouse direction is Left-Right and `this.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World)` rotates the model in its Y-direction. Now I would like to use `eventData.delta.y` to rotate the model in X axis. How do I rotate the model in X axis as well?

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Rotate360Model: MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {
     public float rotationSpeed;
     public float rotationDamping;

     private float _rotationVelocity;
     private float _preRotationVelocity;
     private float _preRotationVelocityY;
     private float _rotationVelocityY;
     private bool _dragged;

     public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
         _dragged = true;
     }

     public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
         _preRotationVelocity = eventData.delta.x * rotationSpeed;
         _rotationVelocity = Mathf.Clamp (_preRotationVelocity, -5f, 5f);
         this.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World);

         _preRotationVelocityY = eventData.delta.y * rotationSpeed;
         _rotationVelocityY = Mathf.Clamp (_preRotationVelocityY, -5f, 5f);
         transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, _rotationVelocityY, Space.World);
     }

     public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
         _dragged = false;
     }

     private void Update () {
         if (!_dragged && !Mathf.Approximately (_rotationVelocity, 0)) {
             float deltaVelocity = Mathf.Min (
                 Mathf.Sign (_rotationVelocity) * Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping,
                 Mathf.Sign (_rotationVelocity) * _rotationVelocity
             );
             _rotationVelocity -= deltaVelocity;
             this.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World);
         }

         if (!_dragged && !Mathf.Approximately (_rotationVelocityY, 0)) {
             float deltaVelocity = Mathf.Min (
                 Mathf.Sign (_rotationVelocityY) * Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping,
                 Mathf.Sign (_rotationVelocityY) * _rotationVelocityY
             );
             _rotationVelocityY -= deltaVelocity;
             this.transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, -_rotationVelocityY, Space.World);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `rotates the model in its Y-direction` .. no it doesn't .. it rotates the object on the **WORLD** Y-axis .... what exactly are you trying to achieve? `Rotate` has an overload taking three Euler axis values `Rotate(float x, float y, float z, Space space = Space.Self)` so simply pass in your desired X and Y rotation and `0` for the Z axis ... and then define either `Space.World` or keep the default `Space.Self` ....

Comment: I would like to rotate my object in X and Y axis. Currently it rotates in Y axis. Right now I am using ```this.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World);``` which rotates in Y axis, so how do I convert this to the 3 axes like you mentioned? Could you please post an answer?

Comment: I think I just did: `transform.Rotate(xAngle, -_rotationVelocity, 0, Space.World);`

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand what xAngle is over here :D

Comment: will whatever you will calculate that your object should rotate in that frame ... you will probably just do the same calculation you did for getting the `-_rotationVelocity` value also for the X axis

Comment: @derHugo I have updated my code, now the object rotates in all 3 axes :(

Comment: well you have a rotation on two world space axis. Is your goal rather a rotation on the objects local axis?

Comment: Hmm I just want my object to rotate in X/Y depending on the mouse direction that is all :/ If that means rotating on its local axis then yes.

Comment: Well there is only two options: You either rotate it around the world axes then yes it will change all three values of the rotation in the Inspector which is the **local** rotation relative to the parent. Or you rotate in the local space .. as said in that case just pass in `Space.Self` (or no space at all as `Space.Self` is the default anyway)

Comment: @derHugo I did Space.Self but it still affects the rotation, I am still confused as to what could be the right solution.

Comment: well after you rotate your object around its Y axis it X axis points now in another direction as well .... it is quite difficult to understand how your desired behaviour should look like exactly and how your code looks now after you already tried things

Answer (score 0):

I guess the object won't rotate, cause you don`t drop this script on some Canvas child object with Image component.

Try to create some Canvas child object with Image component (stretch to full screen and make transparent) and drop `OnDragListener.cs` on it.

There are using `Action<Vector2> Dragged` for transfer X and Y deltas for rotation.

```
using System; 
using UnityEngine.EventSystems; 
using UnityEngine;

public class OnDragListener : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler 
{
    public event Action<Vector2> Dragged;
    public event Action EndedDrag;

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Dragged?.Invoke(eventData.delta);
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        EndedDrag?.Invoke();
    } 
}
```

Then drop `OnDragHandler.cs` on your object, that you need rotate. Don`t forget to put OnDragListener in the field.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OnDragHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private OnDragListener _onDragListener;
    [SerializeField] private float _rotationSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float _rotationDamping;
   
    private bool _dragged;
    private float _rotationVelocity;

    private void Start()
    {
        _onDragListener.Dragged += OnDragHandle;
        _onDragListener.EndedDrag += OnEndDragHandle;
    }

    private void OnDragHandle(Vector2 delta)
    {
        _rotationVelocity = CalculateRotationVelocity(delta.x);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World);

        _rotationVelocity = CalculateRotationVelocity(delta.y);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, _rotationVelocity, Space.World);

        _dragged = true;
    }

    private float CalculateRotationVelocity(float delta)
    {
        float preRotationVelocity = delta * _rotationSpeed;
        return Mathf.Clamp(preRotationVelocity, -5f, 5f);
    }

    private void OnEndDragHandle()
    {
        _dragged = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!_dragged && !Mathf.Approximately(_rotationVelocity, 0))
        {
            float deltaVelocity = Mathf.Min(
                Mathf.Sign(_rotationVelocity) * Time.deltaTime * _rotationDamping,
                Mathf.Sign(_rotationVelocity) * _rotationVelocity
            );
            _rotationVelocity -= deltaVelocity;
            this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass on `eventData.delta` as a `Vector2` instead of independent `float`

Comment: You can just pass on `eventData.delta` directly ;) `Vector2` is a `struct` and therefor anyway passed by value (copy)